# How to cancel and return to app from twitter integration in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am integrating Twitter to my iPhone app.I am facing an issue on Twitter Login page.When I click on "Cancel, and return to app" link. Activity indicator view get displayed for long time and goes nowhere and Twitter Login Page doesn't get dismissed.

[image: Twitter Login Page]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from Twitter developer website there Go to MyApplication -> Settings and in Settings there is a field Website.I filled the field with my own website url.It solved my problem.